# Trouble installing AngularFire in Ionic project

Tags: angular, npm, ionic-framework, angularfire

I would highly appreciate any help with installing **AngularFire** in **Ionic 6** project. error says:  `Packages installation failed, see above.` here is my setup:

```
>> ionic info


Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.0.1 (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.12.1\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.6.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 15.2.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 15.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 15.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 8.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 4.7.1
   @capacitor/android : not installed
   @capacitor/core    : 4.7.1
   @capacitor/ios     : not installed

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.7.2

System:

   NodeJS : v18.12.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 8.19.2
   OS     : Windows 10

>> ng add @angular/fire@latest --skip-confirmation

ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Package information loaded.
✖ Packages installation failed, see above.




 >> npm outdated
 
Package                             Current    Wanted    Latest  Location                                        
@angular-devkit/build-angular        15.2.4    15.2.5    15.2.5  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular      
@angular/cli                         15.2.4    15.2.5    15.2.5  node_modules/@angular/cli                       
@angular/common                      15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/common                    
@angular/compiler                    15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/compiler                  
@angular/compiler-cli                15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli              
@angular/core                        15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/core                      
@angular/forms                       15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/forms                     
@angular/language-service            15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/language-service          
@angular/platform-browser            15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser          
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic    15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic  
@angular/router                      15.2.4    15.2.6    15.2.6  node_modules/@angular/router                    
@capacitor/cli                        4.7.1     4.7.1     4.7.3  node_modules/@capacitor/cli                     
@capacitor/core                       4.7.1     4.7.1     4.7.3  node_modules/@capacitor/core                    
@ionic/angular                        6.6.3     6.7.2     7.0.1  node_modules/@ionic/angular                     
@ionic/angular-toolkit                8.0.0     8.1.0     9.0.0  node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit             
@types/jasmine                        4.0.3     4.0.3     4.3.1  node_modules/@types/jasmine                     
@types/node                        12.20.55  12.20.55  18.15.11  node_modules/@types/node                        
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin      5.3.0     5.3.0    5.58.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin   
@typescript-eslint/parser             5.3.0     5.3.0    5.58.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser          
eslint                               7.32.0    7.32.0    8.38.0  node_modules/eslint                             
eslint-plugin-import                 2.22.1    2.22.1    2.27.5  node_modules/eslint-plugin-import               
eslint-plugin-jsdoc                  30.7.6    30.7.6    40.3.0  node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsdoc                
eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow            1.2.2     1.2.2     1.2.3  node_modules/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow         
ionicons                              6.1.3     6.1.3     7.1.0  node_modules/ionicons                           
jasmine-core                          4.3.0     4.3.0     4.6.0  node_modules/jasmine-core                       
jasmine-spec-reporter                 5.0.2     5.0.2     7.0.0  node_modules/jasmine-spec-reporter              
rxjs                                  7.5.7     7.5.7     7.8.0  node_modules/rxjs                               
ts-node                               8.3.0     8.3.0    10.9.1  node_modules/ts-node                            
typescript                            4.8.4     4.8.4     5.0.4  node_modules/typescript                         
zone.js                              0.11.8    0.11.8    0.13.0  node_modules/zone.js
```

more detailed error :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/service-worker@15.2.6
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"15.2.4" from @angular/forms@15.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     peer @angular/forms@">=12.0.0" from @ionic/angular@6.6.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!       @ionic/angular@"^6.1.9" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/google-maps@15.2.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/google-maps
npm ERR!     @angular/google-maps@"^15.2.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"15.2.6" from @angular/service-worker@15.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/service-worker
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/service-worker@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   @angular/service-worker@"^15.2.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@15.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"15.2.6" from @angular/service-worker@15.2.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/service-worker
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/service-worker@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/service-worker@"^15.2.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Comment: use with `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force`

Answer (score 0):

Update your angular version to (15.2.6) with ng update, then try it again. The issue should disappear.